# Как в wp_remote_request обработать таймаут?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет!
Делаю запрос через wp_remote_request с заданным тайм аутом, не понимаю как мне обрабатывать ситуацию если в заданный тайм аут ответ не пришел ?

Comment: Приведите ваш код в тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

При ошибке возвращается объект класса WP_Error.

```
$response = wp_remote_request( 'http://site.org', $args );
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    echo esc_html( 'Ошибка: ' . $response->get_error_message() );
}
```